# Are questions that could be on topic, but asked without a parenting role, still on topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope, asking-questions

I think the title is quite self-explanatory, but let's explain it a bit more.

I am hesitating asking a question here. The question itself (~20-year-old with a behavior I need help handling) would be on topic if I were a parent.
However, I am not directly related to that person, at least not in a way that would qualify as "parenting" (not father/son/guardian/keeper...).

Would such a question be on topic? Should I rephrase it as if I were in a parenting position and deal with the interpretation of the answer? Is it plain off topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely. If you look in the Related sidebar to the right, you will see we have a few meta posts on this already.

From our [Help page](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> We welcome questions on topics like these:
>
> matters of upbringing,
> safety considerations,
> food and feeding,
> health and hygiene,
> development and growth,
> language development,
> behavior and social skills,
> discipline and punishment,
> childrens'/family games for developmental purposes or parental sanity.

.... but also:

> Please note that opinions shared here should be backed up either with a reference, or experiences that happened to you personally. Also, posts that primarily exist to push a specific agenda (propaganda), and soap-boxing, are not welcome.